# Using alloy instances for creating Java instances and automatically generate testcase

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, formal-methods, alloy

I want to use alloy4 for an automated testcase generation research project. can anyone plz help me with this ?
how can I use alloy for creating java instance objects by using alloy generated instances ?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if it seems like a resurrected zombie, but [jDolly](http://code.google.com/p/jdolly/) is a java program generator based on Alloy. Check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Concerning generating test cases using SAT, I know that Dr. Sarfraz Khurshid, who teaches in UT Austin wrote his thesis "Generating Structurally Complex Tests from Declarative Constraints" and is based on SAT solving (alloy in his case). You can find his thesis online.

To quote from the abstract,

> **This dissertation describes a method for systematic constraint-based test generation for programs that take as inputs structurally complex
>   data, presents an automated SAT-based framework for testing such
>   programs**

.

However, I am not familiar with any work on creating java classes from alloy specifications.